# Picard group of $(SL(n)\times SL(m))$-orbits

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, divisors, homogeneous-spaces, picard-group

Let $\mathbb{P}^N$ be the projective space of $n\times m$ matrices with complex entries modulo scalar. Consider the $(SL(n)\times SL(m))$-action on $\mathbb{P}^N$ given by $((A,B),Z)\mapsto AZB^{T}$. Now, consider the matrix
$$
J_k = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
I_{k} & 0 \\ 
0 & 0
\end{array} 
\right)
$$
and let $X_k\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ be the orbit of $J_k$. I would like to ask if anyone knows how to compute the Picard group of $X_k$.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/379182/4149).

Comment: See also  Proposition 6.10 in Sansuc's paper [Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002198746&physid=phys48#navi)

Comment: Thank you. Following the argument you used here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379171/picard-group-of-mathrmgln-orbits/379182#379182 it seems that $\text{Pic}(X_n)\cong \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ while $\text{Pic}(X_k)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ for $k< n$. The parity of $k$ does not seem to play any role here. Is this correct?

Comment: Write $G={\rm SL}(n)\times{\rm SL}(n)$, and let $H$ denote the stabilizer of $J_k$. Then ${\rm Pic }\,X_k$ is canonically isomorphic to the character group of $H$. What is $H$ in your case?

Comment: It is the subgroup made of pair of matrices $(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B \\ 
0 & C
\end{array} \right), \left(\begin{array}{cc}
A' & B' \\ 
0 & C'
\end{array} \right))$ such that $AA'^{T} = \lambda I_k$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $G={\rm SL}(n)\times {\rm SL}(n')$ and let $H\subset G$ denote the stabilizer of $J_k$ in $G$. We write ${\frak X}(G)$ for the character group of $G$. Then ${\frak X}(G)=0$. We have a canonical isomorphism ${\rm Pic}\,X_k\cong {\frak X}(H)$;
see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/379182/4149).
See also  Proposition 6.10 in Sansuc's paper [Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=GDZPPN002198746&physid=phys48#navi).

For $g\in G={\rm SL}(n)$, $g'\in{\rm SL}(n')$,
we write $g=\begin{pmatrix} A&B\\C&D \end{pmatrix}$,
$g'=\begin{pmatrix} A'&B'\\C'&D' \end{pmatrix}$,
where $A,A'$ are $k\times k$ square matrices,
$D$ is an $(n-k)\times(n-k) $-square matrix,
and $D'$ is an $(n'-k)\times(n'-k)$-square matrix.
To compute $H$, we solve the equation
$$ g\, J_k\, g^{\prime\, T}=\lambda J_k, \quad\lambda\in K^\times,$$
where $K$ is the base field.
We obtain
$$C=0,\quad  C'=0,\quad  AA^{\prime\, T}=\lambda I_k.$$

We assume that $k\ge 1$. If $n>k$ and $n'>k$, then the character group ${\frak X}(H)$
is generated by the the characters:
$$d_A=\det A,\quad d'_A=\det A',\quad \lambda,\quad d_D=\det D,\quad d'_D=\det D',$$
satisfying the relations (written additively)
$$ d_A+d_D=0,\quad d'_A+d'_D=0,\quad  d_A+d'_A=k\lambda. $$
We see that ${\frak X}(H)$ is a free abelian group with two generators $d_A$ and $\lambda$, and hence ${\rm Pic}\,X_k\simeq {\Bbb Z}\oplus {\Bbb Z}$.

If $n=k$ but $n'>k$, then we have $d_D=0$, and hence $d_A=0$. We see that ${\frak X}(H)$ is a free abelian group with one generator $\lambda$,
and hence ${\rm Pic}\,X_k\cong {\Bbb Z}$.

Similarly, if $n'=k$ but $n>k$, then we have $d'_D=0$, and again
${\rm Pic}\,X_k\cong {\Bbb Z}$.

Finally, if  $n=k$ and  $n'=k$, then we have $d_D=0$ and $d'_D=0$, whence
$d_A=0$, $d'_A=0$, and $k\lambda=0$.
We see that ${\frak X}(H)\cong {\Bbb Z}/k {\Bbb Z}$ with generator $\lambda$,
and hence  ${\rm Pic}\,X_k\cong {\Bbb Z}/k {\Bbb Z}$ in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much. If we take $G = GL(n)\times GL(n')$ instead of $G = SL(n)\times SL(n')$ as in your previous answer then in the case $k < n$ and $k < n'$ we have that the Picard group is generated by $d_{A},d_{A'},\lambda$ with the relation $d_{A}+d_{A'} = k\lambda$ right?

Comment: No. Then ${\frak X}(H)$ is generated  by $d_D,\ d'_D,\ d_A,\ d'_A,\ \lambda$ with one relation $d_A+d'_A=k\lambda$, and hence ${\rm Pic}\, X_k\simeq {\Bbb Z}^4$.

Comment: I think that looking at the cokernel $d_D,d'_{D}$ should not appear anymore.

Comment: You are right. Now ${\frak X}(G)$ is a free abelian group of rank 2 with generators $d=\det g$ and $d'=\det g'$. The restriction map sends $d$ to $d_A+d_D$ and it sends $d'$ to  $d'_A+d'_D$. Since ${\rm Pic}\, X_k\cong{\rm coker}[{\frak X}(G)\to{\frak X}(H)]$, in the case  $n>k$, $n'>k$ we obtain  ${\rm Pic}\, X_k\simeq {\Bbb Z}^2$.